# List comprehension for dict in dict

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have the following python dictionary (a dict in a dict):

```
d = {'k1': {'kk1':'v1','kk2':'v2','kk3':'v3'},'k2':{'kk1':'v4'}}
```

I can't get my brains to figure out the list comprehension to get a list of all values (v1, v2...).  If you can give my an example with a lambda also, that you be nice.

The goal is to have  values_lst = ['v1','v2','v3','v4']

Thanks

Comment: It helps to write it as a regular loop first and then change it to a list comprehension. What have you tried?

Comment: Flatten the dict heirarchy; iterate over the values.

Comment: Thanks. Very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine two loops to "flatten" the dict of dicts. Loop over the values of `d` first, and then loop over the values of the values of `d`. The syntax might be a bit hard to grasp at first:

```
values_lst = [v for x in d.values() for v in x.values()]
```